# LINQ Nested Condition

Tags: linq

Sorry, I've searched and read through about a dozen related posts but didn't quite find what I needed...

I want to return objects like so:

```
((Status == 1 || Status == 2) && Value = 'Green')
```

Of course I can't use parentheses in Linq as I can in SQL.  I've tried the following:

```
list.Where(x => x.Status == 1 || x.Status == 2)
    .Where(x => x.Value == 'Green')

// or...
list.Where(x => x.Value == 'Green')
    .Any(x => x.Status == 1 || x.Status == 2)

// or...
list.Where(x => x.Status == 1 || x.Status == 2)
    .Any(x => x.Value == 'Green')
```

(or multiple other variations thereof)

Is one method any more "correct" than another?

While I can bludgeon some results out of it, I have two main concerns:

1. Which is the accepted best practice (if there is one), and
2. My indexes are optimized for the Status predicate first... is Linq smart enough to realize this, and/or does a certain version of the above ensure that the index predicates are propagated in the optimal order?

Comment: What's wrong with `x => ((x.Status == 1 || x.Status == 2) && x.Value = 'Green')`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - nothing apparently... that was the first thing I tried but I must have had some syntax wrong (the actual condition is more complex).  Your comment prompted me to retry that and seems well now.  Still half curious about #2 in my question, but if you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression should work:

```
.Where(x => (x.Status == 1 || x.Status == 2) && x.Value = 'Green')
```

The first expression from the list of alternatives, i.e.

```
list.Where(x => x.Status == 1 || x.Status == 2)
    .Where(x => x.Value == 'Green')
```

is its logical equivalent. When LINQ is translated to some RDBMS, these two approaches produce equivalent SQL. When LINQ is used in memory, the two `Where` clauses are executed one after the other, but the overall result is the same.

Alternatives #2 and #3 are not the same, because `Any(...)` produces `true` or `false` depending on presence or absence of records matching their predicate among the results.